# Can I query across subcollections with firestoreConnect?

Tags: firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I read that Firestore can now query across subcollections. Is the firestoreConnect HOC from react-redux-firebase capable of utilizing this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collection Group Queries were released at Google I/O last week (May 7, 2019). A quick scan of the [`react-redux-firebase` release notes](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/releases) shows no mention of them at this time, so it seems like they're not supported yet. You might want to [file an issue/feature request for it](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues) and monitor said release notes for updates.

Answer (score 0):

I read about that too. There is info about how to perform subcollection queries here: [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). I am not sure about react-redux however, what are your intentions?

Comment: I use firestoreConnect to allow components to be loaded with firestore data as props. Logically, the collections I query from would be in a hierarchy, but as I need to query across all docs of each collection, I keep them all as top level collections. If firestoreConnect has been updated to include this feature, I could store my collections underneath each other as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
//To query all subcolections with react-redux-firebase useFirestoreConnect function, use:

useFirestoreConnect([
    {
      collectionGroup: "COLLECTION_GROUP_NAME",
      storeAs: "ANY_NAME",
    },
  ]);


//To Read and save to a variable

  let YOUR_VAR = useSelector(
    (state) => state.firestore.ordered.ANY_NAME
  );
```